# Instantiate RLMObject on RealmSwift 0.92.3

Tags: swift, realm

I updated to latest realmswift, I have lots of code to update and  one of this is the problem.

Before I just called `RLMObject` in the statement:

```
for obj = obj as? RLMObject
```

now it crashes. Is there any other options?

```
for obj in Realm().objects(ImageBackgrounds)
{
    if let obj = obj as? [what?] // <- what to write here? 
    {
        let image = UIImage(data: obj.[unknown??])

        if (obj.[realmImageName???unknown] == "image\(slideshowSequence)")
        {
           // Do Something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Isnt in the new realm Object instead of RLMObject?

Answer (score 2):

Realm returns objects of the given type now, so you don't have to check for object type anymore. 
So you just write:

```
for obj in Realm().objects(ImageBackgrounds)
{
    let image = UIImage(data: obj.[unknown??])

    if (obj.[realmImageName???unknown] == "image\(slideshowSequence)")
    {
       // Do Something
    }
}
```

and your `obj` type is already `ImageBackgrounds`.